# How to stop an activity from reloading on orientation changes

Tags: android

I have an activity as a child within a navigation drawer parent activity, any time the orientation of the pages changes the page has to be reloaded again.

```
public class ApplicationsClass extends NavigationDrawer implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_list_activity, frameLayout);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            //I do my stuffs here

        }
    }

    ...
}
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <!-- Main activity. -->
    <application
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode">

        <!-- Register Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".ApplicationsClass">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    ...
    </application>
```

I have tried adding `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"` to my application tag in the androidmanifest as some articles suggested but to no avail. Please is there a way to stop reloading the page upon orientation changes in android. I would be grateful if someone could help. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I had also tried adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to my activity within the androidmanifest.xml but to no avail.

I just realized that adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` only works when i am had not extended the class from the `navigationdrawer` and thereby making it a fragment with the navigationdrawer class. This only works when it is not in a fragment layout form.

Comment: In your question you are talking about stopping reloading ? and below in description you are saying it has to be reloaded ?

Comment: @Arslan Please where in my description did i say it has to be reloaded

Comment: I have an activity as a child within a navigation drawer parent activity, any time the orientation of the pages changes the page has to be reloaded again. this.

Comment: I am talking about how my activity currently behave. And I later quoted how I can stop it "Please is there a way to stop reloading the page upon orientation changes in android."

Comment: I would have thought that  below answer would work.

Comment: @Arslan I have tried that, but it didnt work

Comment: Try add `keyboardHidden`, that means `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` or `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" `

Comment: I just realized that adding android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" only works when i am had not extended the class from the navigationdrawer and thereby making it a fragment within the navigationdrawer class. This only works when it is not in a fragment layout form.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in `activity` tag not in `application` tag

```
<activity
        android:name=".ApplicationsClass"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I just realized that adding android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" only works when i am had not extended the class from the navigationdrawer and thereby making it a fragment within the navigationdrawer class. This only works when it is not in a fragment layout form.